# Removing none matching elements with Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have an `h1` heading above each table, I want to remove any `td.tablecells` where the date does not match the date in the `h1.heading` directly above. In the first example it would be to remove the td containing Sat 19 Jun as it doesn't match.

I'm using this below but it removes all `td.table-cell`, I need something extra to keep the td with the matching date. I'm struggling because the H1 is sitting outside the table and I can seem to get that final match.

```js
$(".date-span").filter(function() {
  return $(this).text() !== $(".heading").text();
}).closest('.table-cell').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="heading">Fri 18 Jun</h1>
<table>
  <tr class="tablerow">
    <td class="tablecell"><span class="date-span">Fri 18 Jun</span></td>
    <td class="tablecell"><span class="date-span">Sat 19 Jun</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<h1 class="heading">Fri 19 Aug</h1>
<table>
  <tr class="tablerow">
    <td class="tablecell"><span class="date-span">Fri 19 Aug</span></td>
    <td class="tablecell"><span class="date-span">Sat 20 Aug</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `$(".heading").text()` will get *all* of the heading texts - as you have multiple, it combines all of them `console.log($(".heading").text()) == "Fri 18 JunFri 19 Aug 4"` so they never match.

Answer (score 3):

Use DOM relationship to get [`.prev()`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) sibling i.e. *heading* of parent `table` in the test condition

And, Use correct selector i.e. `'.tablecell'` instead of `'.table-cell'`

```js
$(".date-span").filter(function() {
  return $(this).text().trim() !== $(this).closest('table').prev(".heading").text().trim();
}).closest('.tablecell').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="heading">Fri 18 Jun</h1>
<table>
  <tr class="tablerow">
    <td class="tablecell"><span class="date-span">Fri 18 Jun</span></td>
    <td class="tablecell"><span class="date-span">Sat 19 Jun</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<h1 class="heading">Fri 19 Aug</h1>
<table>
  <tr class="tablerow">
    <td class="tablecell"><span class="date-span">Fri 19 Aug</span></td>
    <td class="tablecell"><span class="date-span">Sat 20 Aug</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

As per comments updated HTML,  You can traverse up to `.closest('.timetable-outer')` then use `.prev()`

```js
$(".date-span").filter(function() {
  return $(this).text().trim() !== $(this).closest('.timetable-outer').prev(".heading").text().trim();
}).closest('.table-times').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="heading">Wednesday 18 July</h1>
<div class="timetable-outer">
  <div class="production">
    <div class="title">A title</div>
    <table class="timetable-inner">
      <tbody>
        <tr class="table-row">
          <td class="table-times"> <span class="date-span">Wednesday 18 July</span> </td>
          <td class="table-times"> <span class="date-span">Thursday July 19</span> </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it is deleting all <td class="table-times">. I've tried everything using jsfidddle not sure where I'm going wrong, [link]https://jsfiddle.net/kdrysdale/xpvt214o/438282/

Comment: @ultrarun, In heading you have `Friday 20 July` and table cell has `Friday July 20` hence none matches

Comment: Haha, oh man I can't believe I missed that! Now works, thanks for your help on this.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working demo: https://codepen.io/creativedev/pen/XBKoYN

```
$(".date-span").filter(function() {
return $(this).text().trim() != $(this).parents('table:first').prev(".heading").text().trim();
}).closest('.tablecell').remove();
```